# Assignt automatically two categories by author

Tags: categories, author, automation

I'm looking for a way to automatically assign two categories each time an author makes a blog post:

1. General category (will always be the same for all authors).
2. Author category, with de same exact name as the author.

For example, assign to a new blog post from user Bilbo the generic category 'TLOFT' and the author tag 'Bilbo'.

I'm sure this won't be really complicated, but I'm just starting and I get lost when away from html, css and minimum java...

Hope anybody can help! Thanks in advance!

Edit --> This is the structure:

[image: problem example]

Comment: Welcome to WPSE and WP. Why do you want to create author-specific categories? WordPress already has built-in Author Archives, so you can see all the posts published by a specific author.

Comment: I agree with WebElaine that _entities are not to be multiplied without necessity_. If you certainly need the user-restricted categories, do the following: 1) Create the new category on each `user_register`. 2) Limit the user to both personal and default categories. 3) Assign those categories to the user's posts on `save_post`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help!

I have multiple blogs on the web: one on each 'project' (that is the same as the username and category), and one general filterable blog. So, I assumed that it would be better to add this automation; this way I won't have to create myself each category, and/or 'trust' that the users will use only the specific category.

What I'm thinking now is that the common category ('TLOFT' in the example) is unnecessary, as I can show all categories on the home page, but the automation is still needed because of the filterable blog. What do you think?